# QGIS: Shortest Path (network analysis) not working properly

Tags: qgis, vector, shortest-path, network-analysis

My task is to connect all green points with the blue point by individual lines:
[image]

I have created a path network with the following steps:

1. extract the data of streets and roads from OSM with the plugin "QuickOSM"
2. I created lines between the green points and the streets using the "shortest line between features" tool, as well as a line for the blue point
3. I merged the lines from 1. and 2. into one line layer and use it in 4. as the network layer
4. Using the tool "shortest path (layer to point) I tried to generate all the individual lines I am looking for

However, the error always states "there is no route from start point to end point".

Any ideas on what the issue might be - or on how to solve it with another aproach?

---

UPDATE:

It seems like connecting lines from the tool "shortest line between features" sometimes do NOT CONNECT as intended.

The orange points created with "line intersection" show, that not all lines are connected. Same issue appears with other tools like "split with lines".

[image]

Comment: did you remember to mark the lines as both ways instead of one way?

Comment: Do you mean the direction within the shortest path tool? Yes it was set to both directions.

Comment: Did you split your original road layer at each address spur intersection so that there is a junction? It's not explicitly stated in your steps.

Comment: I did that later on yes, some paths then were generated but the majority wasn't. I'll give the solution by BERA a try, this might fix it.